# How to take multiple pictures using camera in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application in which I have a requirement to take multiple images in one shot by phone camera. User don't want to open camera again and again.

I have tried https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin Plugin also but it do not support continuous Images capturing. It clicks one image at a time.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Can you try this in media plugin
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{

                            file = await MediaPicker.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions { SaveToAlbum = true, Name = "", Directory = "" });
                            if (file != null)
{
//code to save
}

The user can press cancel at anytime to stop taking pictures, and it'll hit the return and stop running the code. But its ran the logic to save the images each time a photo has been taken.
```